# Data visualisation ideas

Tags: python, data-visualization

I'll try explaining this with a general example:

Lets say my dataset has been classified into 4 variables : A,B,C,D. The variables have been divided into 3,4,5 and 6 equal classes respectively, and the data in each variable is then grouped into these classes based on the boundaries of each class. This would result into 3x4x5x6 = 360 total classes. Now 360 subsets of the dataset have been created, each containing the corresponding classes from each variable (for example Subset X(1,1,1,1) would contain the first class from each variable, and so on until X(3,4,5,6)). The density of each subset is calculated and then grouped into a 3x4 Matrix consisting of 5x6 matrices.

How can one visualise this for n variables and a random number of classes for each variable? Any suggestions where I could learn more about this?

Comment: What would you like to visualize? Distribution? Line plots? Relationship between variables?

Comment: I want to visualise the combined effect of all the variables. They are basically independent from each other. A heat map would be most ideal

Comment: The combined effect on what exactly? :)

Comment: Assuming my variables are humidity and temperature, what combination would most likely result in rain